# Android Flavors :Applying only flavor specific code to a source set

Tags: android, android-flavors

I am running into some trouble with source sets, I have a main source set that contains most of the common code but then a build flavor switch was included by the previous developer for example :

```
    if (Application.inKiosk) {
        navigation.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        val employeeSelectionFragment = EmployeeSelectionFragment()
        employeeSelectionFragment.setAllList(employees)
        employeeSelectionFragment.setCallback(employeeSelected)
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.small_container, employeeSelectionFragment, "EmployeeSelectionFragment").commitNow()
        currentTimeRecord = TimeRecord()
    } else {
        setupTimeRecords(employees!!.first()!!.id, savedInstanceState == null)
    }
```

I want to extract this flavor specific block and include it in its own source set folder. I can't get access to the common members though such as navigation. How would I extract this section ?

```
        navigation.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        val employeeSelectionFragment = EmployeeSelectionFragment()
        employeeSelectionFragment.setAllList(employees)
        employeeSelectionFragment.setCallback(employeeSelected)
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.small_container, employeeSelectionFragment, "EmployeeSelectionFragment").commitNow()
        currentTimeRecord = TimeRecord()
```

Comment: Create `fun setupKioskMode(navigation: View, supportFragmentManager: FragmentManager): TimeRecord` in some class. Create implementations of that class in each of your flavor-specific source sets, with your desired implementation (e.g., the above code). Have the `main` source set call `setupKioskMode()` from your `if` block in your first snippet shown above.

Comment: Hey commons thanks for the suggestion but is there any way to get rid of the if (Application.inKiosk) { }  from the main source set ?

Comment: Ah, OK. In that case, your function would have some other name (`setupWhatever()`) and would have additional parameters (for those things that you are passing into `setupTimeRecords()`). One source set would implement the function using your `Application.inKiosk` `true` scenario; the other would call `setupTimeRecords()`. Your `main` source set would replace the entire `if`/`else` with a call to `setupWhatever()`, and the right implementation of `setupWhatever()` will be used depending on your build variant.

Comment: This solution worked for me thanks :) !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic recipe for splitting code between product flavors is to:

- Set up 2+ flavors in a dimension
- Create source sets for each of those flavors (`src/flavorOne/`, `src/flavorTwo/`)
- Define some class in both of those flavors
- Have that class implement functions that offer the per-flavor functionality that you are looking for (e.g., `setupTimeRecords()` in one flavor, the in-kiosk code in the other flavor)
- Have your `main` source set use that class and call that function

Gradle will pull in the implementation of the class from the flavor's source set for whatever build variant you are building, and that is the implementation that the `main` code will use in that build.

Comment: From commons suggestion I was able to create two source sets one for a mobile build and one for a tablet build with a common function that implements flavor specific code. Then in my shared source set I just call this function and the correct flavor dependent code is called.